# Preference API storage

Tags: java, preferences

If I use the [Preference API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/) to store user or system preferences, where are they stored on Windows and Unix?

Answer (score 41):

For Windows systemRoot and userRoot are stored in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Prefs** and **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs** respectively.

For Unix systemRoot and userRoot are stored in **"/etc/.java"** and **"${user.home}/.java/.userPrefs"**, respectively.

Note that for Unix the locations can be changed by specifying **"java.util.prefs.userRoot"** and **"java.util.prefs.systemRoot"** properties

Comment: On my UNIX box (which is Mac OS X), I get them in ~/Library/Preferences in multiple plist files. :>

Comment: Mac OS X uses the java.util.prefs.MacOSXPreferencesFactory class.  See http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2010/Jul/msg00056.html for a discussion.

Comment: @RichardNeish I don't see a `MacOSXPreferencesFactory` class in my Mac's JDK: http://i.imgur.com/wWDryFT.png

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero the `java.util.prefs.MacOSXPreferencesFactory` class should be in `rt.jar` in JDK 1.7 or later.  I don't have a Mac, so can't comment further.  See http://hg.openjdk.java.net/macosx-port/macosx-port/jdk/file/65910faed942/src/macosx/classes/java/util/prefs for the source code.

Comment: @RichardNeish well, I'm compiling on JDK 8... and, here's all the items in `java.util.prefs`: http://i.imgur.com/GdpGIVf.png

Answer (score 14):

I have to extend n002213fs' answer, because it seems to me, that the Storage Location is a big mess.
Note that Windows saves it in the *Windows Registry* and Unix saves it in *prefs.xml*-files.

### userRoot

- Windows (32Bit): `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs`
- Windows (64Bit) with JVM (64Bit): `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs`
- Windows (64Bit) with JVM (32Bit): `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Prefs`
- Unix: `System.getProperty("java.util.prefs.userRoot")` **or** *(if the previous value is not set)* `~/.java/.userPrefs`

### systemRoot

- Windows (32Bit): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs`
- Windows (64Bit) with JVM (64Bit): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs`
- Windows (64Bit) with JVM (32Bit): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Prefs`
- Unix: `System.getProperty("java.util.prefs.systemRoot")`  **or** *(if the previous value is not set)* `System.getProperty("java.home")+"/.systemPrefs"` (`System.getProperty("java.home")` might be `/etc/.java/`. You can check it in a terminal with `$JAVA_HOME`.)

Comment: For Unix, note that `FileSystemPreferences` always adds the `.java/.userPrefs` root onto the configured path. Therefore the equivalent default property setting for `java.util.prefs.userRoot` is really just the home directory (or `~` as you put it).