# Storing a file in the user's directory in cross-platform Java

Tags: java, cross-platform, path

I have a Java application that runs on Mac and Windows, directly off a CD/DVD with no installation.  Now, I need to store a file containing per-user data (think favourites etc.) somewhere on the local file system, so that it can be written to.

So, where do you think is a good location for this file? I am thinking something like:

`<USER_DOCUMENTS_AND_SETTINGS>/application data/myapp/favourites.db`     for windows
`<USER_HOME_DIR>/.myapp/favourites.db`                                   for mac/nix

Thoughts? 
And does anyone know the best way to determine these paths within Java?

Answer (score 10):

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

Comment: and I just append "/Application Data" to that? does that folder name ever change depending on localization?

Comment: System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Application Data";

Answer (score 5):

As well as `user.home`, the following is useful for more temporary file storage:

```
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Java Preferences API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html), designed specifically to store user preferences values in a platform independent way we all like. Java will take care of saving them and retrieving from the [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320709/preference-api-storage/1320798#1320798) or other [backing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320709/preference-api-storage/1320798#1320798) store depending on the OS.

These [tutorials](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPreferences/index.html) [can](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-prefapi.html) get you going

Comment: I am already using the preference API for some settings - but this is a *file* that needs storing(db file), not a string setting.

Comment: my take was that *favourites.db* contains key-value pairs for settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider storing the data at [Roaming directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766489(WS.10).aspx) under Windows.