# Looking for a place to store temporary .class files on Windows (some similar app support on Mac)

Tags: java, windows, temporary-files, .class-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing a file in the user’s directory in cross-platform Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570757/storing-a-file-in-the-users-directory-in-cross-platform-java)

I am working on a java project and the java application ends up making some .class files.  Currently, these files are stored inside a projects directory inside the main application directory.  Some people who run the application on a network with a certain version of Novel security software experience issues sometimes when these .class files are created or modified.  I would like to instead always store these files locally but I am unsure of where to store them on the PC version.  On the Mac I think I will store them in application support but I do not know of a similar place on the PC.  Also, it would be best if there was a location that would be good for XP Vista and 7 but if I had to have specific locations for each OS that would be sufficient as well.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570757/storing-a-file-in-the-users-directory-in-cross-platform-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the %AppData% environment variable? I suppose you'd just need to add it to CLASSPATH...

Answer (score 2):

If the app is generating these at runtime, and you don't need them permanently you could also store them in the temp directory. You can access the temp directory in a platform independent way in Java via the system property: `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the "user" directory. In that directory, there's an "appData" directory.

On Vista, it's "C:\Users\Username\AppData".

On XP, i don't quite remember the name. But These are special folders for Windows so I'm sure you can specify one name and go to it directly.

Comment: Note that it's not always there, due to machine policy. The best way is to use the %APPDATA% variable. This also insulates you from needing to differentiate between Windows versions.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I don't usually store files on computers, we use the registry to store info that we need.