# Internationalize a Java Application?

Tags: java, internationalization

I have a `Java Desktop App`, the users of the application have the availability to set the aplications language.

By now i manage it in the database, i call the value of a field called - userLanguage - which is an *Integer*, and when the user has logged in depending on this value i set the corresponding text to each element on the app by using a *switch* ( case 1: set labels text ENGLISH, case 2: set labels text SPANISH ... etc)

But i've heard that control the language from the database is an insult, and i would like to know which's a nice way to do it, or what's the best way to do so, it doesn't matter how difficult it would be but the efficence of the method to internationallize an app is what metters for me.

Comment: you are asking two different question.  I think you should make the internationalization question a different question.

Comment: You should remove the internationalization part from this question, but keep the file part, and open another question for internationalization. But do not use broad terms. Be more specific or your question will be flagged.

Comment: What do you mean with broad terms? give an example or referren please @Evandro

Comment: And @user3294343 and Evandro thanks, i'll separate the questions

Comment: @user3294343 I tried to mean that if you ask the *best* way of doing something will be subject to opinion (if not detailed properly), and is also highly scenario dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually handle this problem using the [Java Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).  It keeps the preferences for each user separately in a system independent way (for you at least).  If you use XML you need to create a SAX/DOM parser or if you use a DB you need to use jdbc.  Neither XML or the DB is a bad or a tough solution, I just think the preferences are the easiest.

For internationalization,  I would use a ResourceBundle that localized for different Locales.  It is a pretty big topic see [The Java internationalization (I18n) tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Java Preferences](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPreferences/article.html) is what you are looking for then.

Or, instead of using XML file you can use [Properties](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

> ...i've heard that control the language from the database is an insult...

I do not agree with that. I think it is scenario dependent, and in your case I think you should keep it the way it is to avoid unnecessary work, unless there is an absolute need for keeping the preferred idiom outside your DB.

Comment: Java Preferences seems nice, but what i don't completely understand how it works and when would it be helpful, can u explain me?

Comment: I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320709/preference-api-storage) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html), it will explain those questions for you.

Answer (score 0):

You've received two answers, both of which are plainly wrong. If you have Java Desktop Application, you should this code:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY);
```

This will give you valid User Interface language for your application - the one user set in his OS preferences. If you want to keep the language in a database or in some kind of preferences, you'll be forcing users to chose language. What for? I've already set what language I want. If you don't have it, let Java fall back to your application's default.
In case you wonder, if you use `ResourceBundle`, the default would be the one without a Locale in its name. That is unless you override this process by using custom `ResourceBundle.Control`.

Comment: Actually you are wrong.  you can use Locale.getDefault()  to get the default Locale.  You can also create a local by using `new Locale("en","GB")`.  There are also constants in the Locale class to help you i.e. Locale.UK .

Comment: Dear @user3294343. I didn't say that you cannot construct a Locale object by calling its constructor, nor did I say that you can't use `Locale.forLanguageTag(String)` for this matter. What I said was, the industry best practice is to detect a locale rather than forcing user to choose the language in each and every application. Regional Properties are here for the reason and correctly internationalized application should observe these properties rather than defining its own.