# Where does the Java Preferences API store data on Mac when a custom path is set?

Tags: java, macos, preferences

For reference, I set the node path to this:

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("/Prefs");
```

I thought that this would store the preferences file in a folder called "Prefs" inside of the working directory for the application I'm developing, but that was not the case. Now I can't find a folder called "Prefs" in the user ~/Library folder or the system /Library folder. I am able to use this preferences object to store data and everything is working as normal.

TL; DR - I can't find where my preferences are being stored based on the given code.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320709/preference-api-storage/1320798

Comment: why do you want to know that? the whole idea of the api is to abstract away the physical location

Answer (score 2):

userRoot() uses the preferences .plist located at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist` and when you set the node() your node will be within the .plist file at `Root/Prefs` in your case